# Eclipse automatically switches to alternative layout files

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, layout

I have two layout files, one located under /layout, and one under /layout-sw550dp. When I choose to open one of them, Eclipse will automatically open the other file (which by itself would be acceptable). However, when I attempt to edit the default layout file, Eclipse will repeatedly switch to the sw-550dp file after about a second, which is incredibly annoying.

Sometimes the switching stops after a few attempts, and other times it continues seemingly forever. Could anyone shed some light on whether this is a bug or feature, and if there are any ways to disable this behaviour? I am using Eclipse 4.2.1 with the Android extras installed.

**UPDATE**

The switching appears to only happen when 'Loading Data for Android X.X' is displayed in the status bar. S a workaround if anyone else is experiencing this is to simply wait until this finishes loading (although it's hardly ideal)

Comment: Im experiencing the exact same problem and as you suggested on the update, it only appears to happens when the 'Loading Data for Android X.X' is on the status bar. I know its a work around and not a fix, but it has been working for me and it spares me quite a bit of frustration while working with it. Thank you for sharing.